# Iterator that supports pushback

Tags: python, iterator

I'm looking for a why to convert a regular iterator into one that supports pushing items back into it.  E.g.

```
item = next(my_iterator)
if went_too_far(item):
    my_iterator.pushback(item)
    break;
```

This is similar, but not identical to, an iterator that supports `peek`; with the latter, the above would look more like this:

```
if went_too_far(my_iterator.peek()):
    break
else:
    item = next(my_iterator)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class PushbackWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.__dict__['_iterator'] = iterator
        self.__dict__['_pushed'] = []

    def next(self):
        if len(self._pushed):
            return self._pushed.pop()
        else:
            return self._iterator.next()

    def pushback(self, item):
        self._pushed.append(item)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._iterator, attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        return setattr(self._iterator, attr, value)
```

To use it:

```
pushback_enabled_iterator = PushbackWrapper(original_iterator)

item = next(pushback_enabled_iterator)
if went_too_far(item):
    pushback_enabled_iterator.pushback(item)
    break;
```