# Python get element pointed by iterator and not move

Tags: python, iterator

Consider the iterator `i = iter([1,2,3,4])`. I am looking for some `current` function that does this:

```
first = next(i) # 1
second = next(i) # 2
second_2 = current(i) # 2
third = next(i) # 3
...
```

I.e., it gives me the current element pointed by the iterator without advancing. How can I do that?

Comment: Can't you just store the last value gotten using `next`?

Comment: In this trivial example yes, but I have a more complicated scenario in which the `current` would be very handy.

Comment: What complication makes remembering the last value a problem?

Comment: I am accessing a global list from withing functions, and want all functions to iterate it together using either `current` or `next` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that iterators have a way to get the current value. The best thing you can do is to use the 'second' variable to reference it.

You can also use libraries or create a custom iterator yourself:

[How to get the current value of a Python iterator - dereferencing an iterator without incrementing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65970365/how-to-get-the-current-value-of-a-python-iterator-dereferencing-an-iterator-wi)

[How to get the item currently pointed at by iterator without incrementing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295937/how-to-get-the-item-currently-pointed-at-by-iterator-without-incrementing)

Answer (score 0):

[Iterator that supports pushback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664103/iterator-that-supports-pushback) gives an implementation of an iterator with pushback.  This should give you the functionality that you need.